# Birthday dosen't appear on frm_Load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reminders

When I try to letting af Label tell me, about a birthday, on a specific date, as set in the code, it does not appear. It still just response with (No birthday).
Can anyone see, what i have done wrong?

```
DateTime bday = Convert.ToDateTime("05-03-2019");
int years = DateTime.Now.Year - bday.Year;
bday = bday.AddYears(years);
DateTime check = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0);
if ((bday > DateTime.Now) && (bday<check))
{
    lblFødselsdag.Text = ("You have birthday");
}
else
{
    lblFødselsdag.Text = ("No birthday");
}
```

The `DateTime.Now.AddDays(0)`, is just made for, if I want later, to let it give me the info a week before.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just checking the day and month, something like `if (DateTime.Now.Day == bday.Day && DateTime.Now.Month == bday.Month) { ... }`?

Comment: This presents a great chance for you to learn **[How to use your Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `bday > DateTime.Now` is false since `DateTime.Now` includes the time of day whereas bday doesn't.
2. "05-03-2019" is being parsed as May 3rd instead of March 5th.

Try this:

```
DateTime bday = Convert.ToDateTime("03-05-2019");

int years = DateTime.Now.Year - bday.Year;
bday = bday.AddYears(years);
DateTime check = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0);
if ((bday >= DateTime.Now.Date) && (bday<check))
{
    lblFødselsdag.Text = ("You have birthday");
}
else
{
    lblFødselsdag.Text = ("No birthday");
}
```

Or simply compare year and month as suggested by @bassfader:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Day == bday.Day && DateTime.Now.Month == bday.Month) { ... }
```

Comment: I have tried your code here, make a complete copy/paste, and it stills return with "No birthday".

Comment: @KasperSøndergaard: It certainly doesn't for me. What if you change the first line to `DateTime bday = Convert.ToDateTime("03-05-2019", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`?

Comment: The last input, did the trick! Thanks for your help! :) I will make it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you add 0 days your "if" looks like this:

```
if(bday>now && bday<now)
```

this "if" will always be false.

The first expression disqualifies the second one.

Comment: Not sure this is quite an answer.

Comment: @spodger I just read the question which was:" Can anyone see, what i have done wrong?" and i pointed out a mistake